# Selecting Distinct in sqlite Android not working

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have the following query in my dbhelper class.

```
public Cursor search(String searchString,String limit){

    searchString=searchString.replaceAll("'", "");

    String[] cols = new String[]{CSV_WORD_ID, CATEGORY_ID, MAIN_TEXT, TRANSLATION_TEXT, PRONUNCIATION_IN_ENGLISH, IMAGE_1,IMAGE_2,IMAGE_3,AUDIO,STATUS};
    Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, WORD_TABLE, cols, CATEGORY_ID + " NOT IN(0,1) AND "+ MAIN_TEXT + " LIKE '%"+searchString+"%' ", null, MAIN_TEXT, null, null, limit);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

In the above function I want to fetch distinct MAIN_TEXT. But in log I can see it is:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT csv_word_id, category_id, main_text, translation_text, pronunciation_in_english, image_1, image_2, image_3, audio, status FROM words WHERE category_id NOT IN(0,1) AND main_text LIKE '%m%'  GROUP BY main_text LIMIT 10
```

I want DISTINCT main_text not csv_word_id. How can I do this.

Comment: Then remove column names other than MAIN_TEXT. String[] cols = new String[]{MAIN_TEXT};

Comment: Hi Febi, basically I want all columns but not repeating with MAIN_TEXT. Actually more than one category may have the same MAIN_TEXT. But I want to fetch distinct.

Comment: Can you try this query "select * from table_name group by distinct_field_needed".

Comment: just wondering what will happen if you put `MAIN_TEXT`  as first column in the columns array?

Comment: i mean `String[] cols = new String[]{MAIN_TEXT , CSV_WORD_ID,...`

Comment: DISTINCT always applies to all columns. Anyway, what should the database return for the other columns, when there are multiple possible source rows?

Comment: then maybe a `group by` required-DISTINCT-column will help ?